# If Statement not working Python while using nmap

Tags: python, if-statement, nmap

I'm having some trouble getting my if statement to work properly. At the end of the iplist.txt there is an empty line that I don't want to run, but for some reason, it's still running. I tried removing the last line of the file but it only removes the last legit line and not the blank line, I even tried removing spaces, empty lines, and null lines but it still would run with a line. And the weirdest part is that the blank runs both in the if block and the else block.

```
 with open ("iplist.txt", "r") as file:
     filecontents = file.read()
     for line in filecontents.split('\n'):
      filename = (line) + ".txt "
      command = "nmap -O -oG " + ".\\ips\\" + (filename) + (line)
      print(command)
      print(filename)
      strlen = int (len(filename))
      print(strlen)
      compareline = line[:4]
      print(compareline)
      if compareline == beginline: #beginline is declared as 10.9 earlier in the file
       print("Testing 1..2...")
       os.system(command)
       filenameforos = (line + ".txt")
       #detailedosdetection = open(filenameforos)
       #next(filecontents)
      else:
       print("Testing...")
       del line
       #next(StopIteration)
```

Here are the contents of iplist.txt

```
10.9.10.38
10.9.10.45
10.9.11.10
#extra line
```

edit

I tried that but it didn't run the loop, I'm sure I'm doing it wrong.

```
with open ("iplist.txt", "r") as file:
 filecontents = file.read()
 lines = file.readlines()
 lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
 print("Creating list")
 for line in lines:
  filename = (line) + ".txt "
  command = "nmap -O -oG " + ".\\ips\\" + (filename) + (line)
  print(command)
  print(filename)
  strlen = int (len(filename))
  print(strlen)
  compareline = line[:4]
  print(compareline)
  if compareline == beginline: #beginline is declared as 10.9 earlier in the file
   print("Testing 1..2...")
   os.system(command)
   filenameforos = (line + ".txt")
   #detailedosdetection = open(filenameforos)
   #next(filecontents)
  else:
   print("Testing...")
   del line
   #next(StopIteration)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please fix your indentation so that the Python code can be run without syntax errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a method to read separate lines. Try

```
lines = file.readlines()
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines] #To remove unneccesary white spaces and "\n"
```

Instead of splitting the file on "\n"

Comment: I tried that but it didn't run the loop, I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. My code is in my original post.

Comment: When you are working with files, it can be useful to imagine a "cursor". Opening the file puts the "cursor" at the beginning of the file. When you call any method that reads the file in some way, it moves the cursor. So when you say `filecontents = file.read()`, the cursor will move all the way to the end of the file. Then when you call `file.readlines()`, it will read everything past the cursor, which is nothing since it's the end of the file. Try removing `filecontents = file.read()`